# Silverlight navigation problems under IIS

Tags: silverlight, iis

I’m totally confused.

I’ve hosted my app under IIS on my machine (windows 7). If then I open IE and enter "http://localhost/MyApp.aspx#SomePage" it will really open the app and then navigate to that “SomePage” page. If then I’ll navigate to another page, address bar updates accordingly (i. e. "http://localhost/MyApp.aspx#SomeOtherPage"). So everything is fine.

But if I enter in browser "http://mypcnetworkname/MyApp.aspx#SomePage" it simply opens my app with the default page and doesn’t navigate to SomePage. If then I'll navigate to another page, address bar also doesn’t update. Navigating through screens doesn’t update nor history frame not address bar and vice verca — looks like browser navigation is disconnected from silverlight navigation (but I’m still able to navigate through application using hyperlinkbuttons in it).

What can I do to make it work? I guess it’s more iis configuration problem (however everything is default, except mime type for silverlight) than related to silverlight.

P. S. It’s an silverlight 4 app but I do have silverlight 5 installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

one way to get around this would be use asp.net to write SomeOtherPage to the launch paramters of the html object.

You then can parse these values when you launch the application and make the switch your self in silverlight

heres a link on passing paramerters: [Link](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/148748.aspx/1)